# UNION in SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to execute the following query, and return a `Cursor`, using `SQLiteDatabase` class:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender
FROM messages;
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT recipient
FROM messages;
```

(the fields `sender` and `recipient` are of the same type.)

I know how to execute the `SELECT DISTINCT` and get 2 cursors holding `sender` and `recipient` columns:

```
c1 = db.query(
        true,                                   //distinct
        Messages.TABLE_NAME,                    //table name
        senderColumn,                           //columns
        null,                                   //where clause
        null,                                   //where args
        null,                                   //group
        null,                                   //having
        sortOrder,                              //sorting order
        null                                    //limit of rows number
);

c2 = db.query(
        true,                                   //distinct
        Messages.TABLE_NAME,                    //table name
        recipientColumn,                        //columns
        null,                                   //where clause
        null,                                   //where args
        null,                                   //group
        null,                                   //having
        sortOrder,                              //sorting order
        null                                    //limit of rows number
);
```

But I can't figure how to `UNION` them (and return a `Cursor`). Also, I may want to specify a **sorting order** on the result. How can I do that? I can't find any mention of `UNION` in [the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: `db.query` is only for simpliest `SELECT` queries. Use `db.rawQuery` instead to use plain SQL

Comment: I see. OK I'll try that thank you